# Activation flash led cause freeze camera in android app

Tags: android, android-camera

i have a little problem (or a big ^^), i've created a custom camera activity for an android app and when i try to activate the flash, the view is freezed :( , but when the activity is launched all is alright .

This is my way to activate the flash

```
if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)) {
        FlashActivation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        FlashActivation.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (inPreview) {
                    camera.stopPreview();
                }

                // NB: if you don't release the current camera before
                // switching, you app will crash
                camera.release();
                camera = Camera.open(currentCameraId);
                Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
                camera.setParameters(p);
                camera.startPreview();

            }
        });
    }
```

If some body can solved the problem it's with pleasure that i accept his solution :D.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to activate flash 
There is no need to stop the preview and restart it.
And there is also no need to release the camera.
you can use this

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
camera.setParameters(parameters);
```